# A problem relating to mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0$, $f^{'}(x)>0 (x\in(0,1))$. Show that there exists $\xi,\eta\in(0,1)$, $\xi+\eta=1$, such that

### $$
\frac{f^{'}(\xi)}{\xi}=\frac{f^{'}(\eta)}{\eta}
$$

My attempts: If $f(x)=x^3$, then $g(x)\equiv\frac{f^{'}(x)}{x}=3x$ is a monotone increasing function. This means that $\xi=\eta=\frac{1}{2}$ will be OK.  In general, I find that 
$$
\Big(\frac{f(x)}{x}\Big)^{'}=\frac{f^{'}(x)}{x}-\frac{f(x)}{x^2}
$$
but I cannot move forward.

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried and done.

Comment: $\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi}=\frac{f(\eta)}{\eta}$ ?

Comment: @Joao:  I have edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\xi=\eta=\frac12$?

But if you enforce $\xi < \eta$, then it is false. Take $f\colon x \to x$. As David Holden suggested in a comment, do you mean that $\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi} = \frac{f(\eta)}{\eta}$ instead?

Comment: No. Just do as it is.  It's homework, actually.

Comment: Then take $1/2$, as I wrote, and you are done.